# API Vendor Testing automation

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, automated-tests, asp.net-web-api2

We have a REST API developed using `Web API 2.0`. This is primarily used by various vendors to write data into our system. The back-end database is `SQL Server`. While on-boarding each vendor, we do a manual verification of the data sent by each vendor just to ensure that the data is not being corrupted by the vendor. Now, we would like to automate this verification process. We have a set of Test cases which we do manually verify.

Is there a out of box tools or products or something which can be readily used to accomplish the verification process?

Comment: you do a one-time manual verification?  How do you verify the data isn't corrupted later?  Really this question is incredibly too vague.

Comment: the manual verification is by asking the vendor provide data satisfying various use cases and this is done in a non-production environment.

Comment: Can you add more details about how do you do the manual verification? Is it by calling REST API? or UI functional test?

Comment: Its a REST API call and the manual testing involves going back to the database and verifying the data submitted